# error when accessing laravel project in ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I have problem when i try to access my webapp in my ubuntu server 16.04..
when i try to type my server ip with the laravel folder it showing this message,

> The requested URL /laravel_spk-matautama/home was not found on this server.

but then i try to put index.php on my link like this url

> http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/laravel_spk-matautama/index.php/home

it works, but the problem is it wont embed the masterpage layout.

[image]

Comment: Try to access like this http://localhost/projectname/public/

Comment: if i try to access localhost it works, but the thing is i want to access the project in my ubuntu server from another client.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this, to access your home page

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/laravel_spk-matautama/public
```

Comment: yes i've tried those link, but it redirected to my login controller, end then it shows me the message, The requested URL /laravel_spk-matautama/public/login was not found on this server.

Comment: Are you set any route for login and what about virtual host. are you set that

Comment: add .htaccess file. hope it should work. make sure mod rewrite enabled.

Comment: i have add the .htaccess file, and about virtual host i've already set it too.